# why this variable is never have a value

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I am checking that if an instance has a value for a specific predicate, bound that value to a specific variable, otherwise, bound that variable to the value 1 of type integer. this is my code

```
select ?boosted where {
    :r1 a ?x
  optional
  {
    ?item rs:boostedBy ?boostedOptional
      bind (if(bound(?boostedOptional), ?boostedOptional, "1"^^xsd:integer) as ?boosted)
  }
}
```

the value of ?boosted is always empty, look please

[image]

why please?

#### Note

I think you don't need data to test why my code is not working, because for me it sounds like a general mistake about using the bound. however, if you want data, i give you data.

#### note2

there is no rs:boostedBy predicate from the first place, so i was looking to have the default value always , which is 1 of type integer in this case.

Comment: "I think you don't need data to test why my code is not working, because for me it sounds like a general mistake about using the bound." That may be true in this case, but it's still a good idea to make sure you provide a [mcve].  If you think the data doesn't matter, then you should make sure that the example query you provide can actually be executed without any data (and still demonstrate the problem).

Answer (score 5):

The IF needs to be outside of the optional graph pattern:

```
SELECT ?boosted WHERE {
    :r1 a ?x
    OPTIONAL{ ?item rs:boostedBy ?boostedOptional . }
    BIND (IF(bound(?boostedOptional), ?boostedOptional, "1"^^xsd:integer) as ?boosted)
}
```

Secondly, I don't see the relationship between the rs:boostedBy property and the {:r1 a ?x} triple pattern.  I.e. are you trying to see if the subject has a boostedBy property?  In that case :r1 and ?item should be the same, i.e. both should be :r1 or both should be ?item, if I'm understanding your intent here.